# Differing .NET XML serializer behavior when deserializing missing integers

Tags: .net, soap, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I recently hit a problem with a SOAP web service where the WSDL specifies an integer for a particular field, but the XML comes in with an empty element which causes the .NET deserialization logic to throw a FormatException.

The WSDL looks like this:

```
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="TransID" type="xsd:int" />
```

And the SOAP looks like this:

```
<TransID></TransID>
```

This causes the exception when parsing the response.  The server I'm talking to belongs to a vendor so I don't have the option to change it.  I'm hacking around this in the short term by redefining the field as a string.

My question is this: In trying to diagnose this problem, I pulled out the XML into a file and created my own XmlSerializer to test deserializing using the POCO's generated by the WSDL import.  The XmlSerializer I created parses this XML just fine and produces the parent type as expected.  No exception.  The field value is zero which would be expected.  Why does the SOAP deserializer puke and the plain deserializer I created works fine?

Comment: If TransID is an int, I wouldn't *expect* it to work as an empty element...

Comment: I don't have an issue with it not working for deserialization.  It's not unreasonable for the deserializer to throw on trying to parse an empty string as an int.  The question was about the differences in behavior.  But after more testing, it turns out that my deserialization test was not diving down into the fields of the parent structure so it gave the appearance that it was successfully deserializing the bad XML because it was returning an object.  But it turns out that it was not deserializing internal fields.  Thus the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is normal and expected; a blank string is not valid as an integer, and cannot be parsed. `XmlSerializer` behaves identically:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var obj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Foo)).Deserialize(
            new StringReader("<Foo><TransID></TransID></Foo>"));
    }
}
public class Foo
{
    public int TransID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should declare your propert as Nullable:

```
public int? TransID { get; set; }
```

This should be enough to make it work when serializing and deserializing the object